# how to show upload progress for each image upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropzone.js

I am using react-dropzone for multiple image upload. The image upload is working but the upload progress is not showing. I could not find on the documentation clearly about showing upload progress. How can we show upload progress in react-dropzone?

I have created a codesandbox too. Here is the link

https://codesandbox.io/s/8BEmjLmo

Here is the code too

```
onDrop = (accepted, rejected) => {
    this.setState({
      accepted,
      rejected
    });
  };


  showFiles() {
    const { accepted } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Dropped files: </h3>
        <ul className="gallery">
          {accepted.map((file, idx) => {
            return (
              <div className="col-md-3" key={idx}>
                <li>
                  <img
                    src={file.preview}
                    className="img-fluid img-responsive"
                    width={200}
                    alt={file.name}
                  />
                  <i
                    className="fa fa-remove"
                    onClick={e => this.handleRemove(file)}
                  />
                  <div className="imageName">{file.name}</div>
                </li>
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
  render() {
    const { accepted } = this.state;
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
    <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
    <Dropzone 
      onDrop={this.onDrop}
      style={style} 
      activeStyle={activeStyle}
      multiple
      accept="image/*"
    >
      Try Dropping file
        </Dropzone>
   {accepted.length !== 0 && this.showFiles()}
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Material-UI LinearProgress bar not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40476405/material-ui-linearprogress-bar-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such feature in react-dropzone as file upload progress. You have to write it yourself, here is an example:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
  if (e.lengthComputable) {
    let percentComplete = e.loaded / e.total;
    console.log(percentComplete);
  }
});

// Just for demo.
xhr.open("POST", "/", true);
xhr.send(null);
```

Another option is to use [React-Dropzone-Component](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/React-Dropzone-Component)

Comment: How can I do this without the xhr. I only have a react component and just set the file in memory and will send them later

Answer (score 1):

Here is my full example that I use with react-dropzone:

```
onDrop(acceptedFiles) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  for (const file of acceptedFiles) formData.append('file', file);

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.upload.onprogress = event => {
   const percentage = parseInt((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
   console.log(percentage); // Update progress here
  };
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState !== 4) return;
    if (xhr.status !== 200) {
     console.log('error'); // Handle error here
    }
     console.log('success'); // Handle success here
  };
  xhr.open('POST', 'https://httpbin.org/post', true);
  xhr.send(formData);
}
```